# get Max Values of array in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

LogicApps Azure:
I have this array, and i need a function for get the value max for each property.

```
[
  {
    "limMec": 18,
    "limMed": 6,
    "maxCons": 1,
    "maxImp": 188.23,
    "maxVeh": 7
  },
  {
    "limMec": 12,
    "limMed": 6,
    "maxCons": 10,
    "maxImp": 200.66,
    "maxVeh": 1
  },
  {
    "limMec": 4,
    "limMed": 9,
    "maxCons": 1,
    "maxImp": 1,
    "maxVeh": 2
  }
]
```

I need a function, not variables !!!
I have not found multiples functions for have a subarray with the differentes results.

Someone know?

With this i can get the value of an element, but not max of the collection:

```
max(body('Seleccionar')[1]['limMec'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this requirement, I provide a sample below for your reference:

**1.** I initialize a variable named `data` and store the same data with yours to simulate your situation.

[image]

**2.** Then add a "[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action)" action and click "**Switch Map to key value mode**", choose the variable  `data` into "**From**" box and write expression `item()?['limMec']` into "**Map**" box.

[image]

**3.** Now, initialize a variable `result` and use the expression `max(body('Select'))`.

[image]

**4.** After running the logic app, we can get the max value of `limMec`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hury, in my post i say "I need a function, not variables !!!" because my code is into a parallel loop, i can't variables into the loop because i need empty for each and the result is 0 when i use in parallel loop.
My loop needs parallel for get shortest time execution.
I can't use your solution for this, thanks !

Comment: Hi @GabrielGordoCarrasco I'm not so clear about your concern. The first "Initialize variable" is to simulate your situation, you don't need this variable. The last "Initialize variable" is to store the result to show you. I think if you don't want variable, you just need to use expression `max(body('Select'))` at last.

Comment: @GabrielGordoCarrasco You can use "Select" action and then use expression `max(body('Select'))` to get the max value, without any variable.

Comment: @GabrielGordoCarrasco If you want to get max value of each property, you need to do the "Select" action for each of them. And I don't think exists a function/method which can get the max value directly in your case. Or you can write code to develop the function and call the function in your logic app.